# How add button on folium map to refresh view

Tags: python, folium

I have some code with folium map. I save map to html. I would like to add button on map under checkbox (with "groups"),  which let me refresh map to default set (reset zoom). Could You help me ?
My code:

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=6)
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name='groups')
m.add_child(fg)
g1 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg, 'group1')
m.add_child(g1)
g2 = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(fg, 'group2')
m.add_child(g2)
folium.Marker([-1, -1]).add_to(g1)
folium.Marker([1, 1]).add_to(g1)
folium.Marker([-1, 1]).add_to(g2)
folium.Marker([1, -1]).add_to(g2)
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)
m.save('mapy_test.html')
```

I found something like this:

```
map.fit_bounds(map.get_bounds())
```

but I don't know how add this to my map.